# GTM - Fire an event when a user receives a specific message

Tags: javascript, tags, google-tag-manager

Whenever I get a message on the page like 'sorry no widgets" I want to send an event to Google Analytics. The message is generated based on user interaction with page (not page load)

The page works like this, a user lands on product page and they can add some other related add-ons. So for example I have a add-on called 'car parking' and there is option YES/NO if they click yes it will go fetch Car parking availability and data without the actual page reloading. The data can take up to 10s to appear. If there is no data I show a user a message "Sorry, no car parking"

I have tried to create variable for "Sorry, no car parking" but it only shows in tag assistant if i click the actual text. So not sure if this is right way to do it?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using custom dataLayer events. First, create your GTM trigger, go to Triggers -> NEW -> Trigger Configuration -> Choose type "Custom Event"

Example:
[image]

Second, go to your GA tag that you wish to fire when you have no widgets and set Triggering rules to your new "StackO" trigger.

Last step is to fire the event. You need to go to piece of code on your Website which actually shows user a message "Sorry, no car parking" - I assume this is a JavaScript function? Let's assume you have code as below:

```
alert("Sorry, no widgets"); //your message to user
//now add code below after you display the message
dataLayer.push({
'event': 'noWidgets'
});
```

Google Dev reference: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide